# How can I use an integer value as 'key' to set value in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

How can I use an integer value as 'key' to set a float value in NSMutableDictionary ?

Comment: As a potential aid to Google searchers: XCode will give the error `Expected method to write array element not found on object of type 'NSMutableDictionary *` on an attempt to use a raw `int` or an `NSInteger` as an NSMutableDictionary key.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As NSDictionarys are only designed to deal with objects, a simple way to do this is to wrap the integer and float in a [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object. For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *testDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[testDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.23f]
                   forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
NSLog(@"Test dictionary: %@", testDictionary);

[testDictionary release];
```

To extract the relevant value, simply use the appropriate intValue, floatValue, etc. method from the NSNumber class.

Comment: It's telling me that the key must be `NSString*`, and searching through `NSKeyValueCoding.h` it looks like all the methods expect strings. Has something changed in the SDK?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/index.html) as it supports integer keys and/or values directly.  No need to box/unbox through NSNumber, but it is also slightly more difficult to set up and use.

Comment: `NSMapTable` is only available in iOS 6 and later.

Comment: NSMapTable holds weak references, which may or may not be what you want. That is different than NSDictionary, though.

Comment: `NSMapInsert` isn't available on iOS. Is there a better way to set an integer value other than something like this: `[map setObject:(__bridge id)((void *)myInt) forKey:myKey];`? I'm assuming the valueOptions were set to `NSPointerFunctionsIntegerPersonality | NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory`.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be an object, so use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger]` instead.

Then, retrieve it with `-integerValue`

Comment: The integerValue method returns an NSInteger object, not an int. :-)

Comment: Ouch, that should be -intValue. Thanks middaparka

Comment: @middaparka: NSInteger is not an object.

Comment: @Simon yes haha, but anyway I decided to point -intValue because I think the OP needs the primitive.

Comment: @Simon Ah.. yes. It's a foundation data type. My bad. (Feel free to ignore the above.) :-)